# Datatype bigger than bigint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, datatypes

I want to use dataype which can hold more than 19 digits. So is there any datatype available which can hold larger than 19 digits?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of problem needs to deal with values in quintillion range? Scientific computing comes into mind.

Comment: @vonPryz The calculation of modular multiplicative inverses for the generation of asymmetric keys is one thing that comes to my mind. It can be used to create a reversible 'randomization' of bigint numbers, for example.

Comment: @vonPryz Late to the game, but barcode numbers, voucher IDs and other long numbers? Or is it better practice to store that as nvarchars?

Comment: @SvendK That really depends. Storing not-really-numbers such as GTIN codes as numbers can cause a lot of headaches. When the leading zeroes [are mandatory](https://www.gs1.org/edi-xml/technical-user-guide/Item_Numbers), using a numeric type is not the smart solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Numeric/Decimal, Float/Real. There's [a great answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158770/61305), some official documentation [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd424925.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx), and I also posted [a few opinions ages ago](http://web.archive.org/web/20110724085550/http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-datatype-should-i-use-for-numeric-columns.html), but here is a quick demonstration:

```
-- overflow error:

DECLARE @x BIGINT        = 9999999999999999999;

GO

-- works:

DECLARE @x DECIMAL(38,0) = 99999999999999999999999999999999999999;
```